# Offline Maps marker Overlapping

Tags: ios, events, titanium, leaflet

I am using the Leaflet JavaScript library to display the offline maps in an iOS application under the Titanium platform.

I am able to show it in my application but I have a problem regarding the click event on multiple markers at the same position.

How can I handle it or cycling the click event on the marker.
First it clicks on one and then another.
Is there any way the library provides, or another way to achieve this.

**Screenshot**

[image]

Please provide me any ideas on how to solve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Leaflet Overlapping Marker Spiderifier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet) or [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) plugins to make this situation more user-friendly.